# Get average time difference grouped by another column in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series

I have a posts table where i'm interested in calculating the average difference between each authors posts. Here is a minimal example:

```sql
+---------------+---------------------+
| post_author   | post_date           |
|---------------+---------------------|
| 0             | 2019-03-05 19:12:24 |
| 1             | 2017-11-06 18:28:43 |
| 1             | 2017-11-06 18:28:43 |
| 1             | 2017-11-06 18:28:43 |
| 1             | 2017-11-06 18:28:43 |
| 1             | 2018-02-19 18:36:36 |
| 1             | 2018-02-19 18:36:36 |
| 1             | 2018-02-19 18:36:36 |
| 1             | 2018-02-19 18:36:36 |
| 1             | 2018-02-19 18:40:09 |
+---------------+---------------------+
```

so for each author, i want to get the delta of their time series essentially, then find the average (grouped by author). so the end result would look something like:

```sql
+---------------+---------------------+
| post_author   | post_date_delta(hrs)|
|---------------+---------------------|
| 0             | 0                   |
| 1             | 327                 |
| 2             | 95                  |
| ...           | ...                 |
+---------------+---------------------+
```

I can think of how to do it in Python, but I'm struggling to write a (postgres) SQL query to accomplish this. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation and arithmetic:

```
select post_author,
       (max(post_date) - min(post_date)) / nullif(count(*) - 1, 0)
from t
group by post_author;
```

The average days is the difference between the maximum and minimum days, divided by one less than the count.